# Subtract value from list

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to subtract a constant value from a list and if the result is less than 0 then the corresponding list entry should be 0.

Here is my code:

```
list = {2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 3, 7, 5, 4};

value = 5;

n = Length[list];

Do[
 If[list[[i]] - value < 0, list[[i]] = 0];
 , {i, 1, n}
 ]

list

{0, 0, 5, 0, 6, 7, 0, 7, 5, 0}
```

How would you solve this, without a loop?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would use [`Clip`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clip):

```
Clip[{2,3,5,4,6,7,3,7,5,4}, {5, Infinity}, {0, 0}]
```

> {0, 0, 5, 0, 6, 7, 0, 7, 5, 0}

Answer (score 17):

You could also use [`Threshold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Threshold.html)

```
list = {2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 3, 7, 5, 4};

value = 5;
```

For the case of integers

```
Threshold[list, value - 1]

(* {0, 0, 5, 0, 6, 7, 0, 7, 5, 0} *)
```

**EDIT:** Comparative timings

```
kumar[list_, value_] := UnitStep[list - value] list

hanlon[list_, value_] := Threshold[list, value - 1]

alan[list_, value_] := If[# < value, 0, #] & /@ list

woll[list_, value_] := Clip[list, {value, ∞}, {0, 0}]

nasser[list_, value_] := 
 ReplacePart[list, Position[list, x_ /; x - value < 0] -> 0]

{#, RepeatedTiming[Do[temp = #[list, value], {10000}]; temp]} & /@ {hanlon, 
   woll, alan, kumar, nasser} // Grid
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot... also for the speed comparison.

Answer (score 14):

Using [`UnitStep`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitStep.html)

```
UnitStep[list - value] list
```

> {0, 0, 5, 0, 6, 7, 0, 7, 5, 0}

Answer (score 5):

I like Anjan solution best. But here is another way

```
list={2,3,5,4,6,7,3,7,5,4};
value=5;
ReplacePart[list, Position[list,x_/;x-value<0]->0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to replace the list items, then I would do

```
list[[Catenate@Position[list, x_ /; x < 5]]] = 0
```

However, if a new list is acceptable (and this is usually a better practice), then I would view this as a simple map:

```
If[# < 5, 0, #] & /@ list
```

Answer (score 3):

This may work for you too:

```
 list = {2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 3, 7, 5, 4};
 value = 5;
 list /. x_ /; x < value :> 0
```

{0, 0, 5, 0, 6, 7, 0, 7, 5, 0}

Answer (score 3):

Here's yet another one, a simple alternative to `Threshold`. It's slower than some of the other ones for integer input, but it's actually the fastest if your values are `Real`s:

```
f[list_, value_] := Chop[list, value]
```

Just to be clear, for integer input, you'd need use `N@list` and then convert the result back to an integer via some form of rounding, which slows down the function.

Running Bob's speedtest:

```
kumar[list_, value_] := UnitStep[list - value] list
hanlon[list_, value_] := Threshold[list, value - 1]
alan[list_, value_] := If[# < value, 0, #] & /@ list
woll[list_, value_] := Clip[list, {value, \[Infinity]}, {0, 0}]
nasser[list_, value_] := ReplacePart[list, Position[list, x_ /; x - value < 0] -> 0]
ender[list_, value_] := Chop[list, value]

list = N@{2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 3, 7, 5, 4};
value = 5;

{#, RepeatedTiming[Do[temp = #[list, value], {10000}]; 
     temp]} & /@ {hanlon, woll, alan, kumar, nasser, ender} // Grid
```

[image]

The integer variant clocks in at about half the speed of Bob's `Threshold` solution.

It's worth noting that this assumes that the values are all positive (because it would also keep values less than `-value`).

Answer (score 2):

I tried to define a function an then map over lists

```
aaa = {2, 7, 6, 0, 11}

f[c_] := If[# - c > 0, # - c, 0] &

f[4] /@ aaa
{0, 3, 2, 0, 7}
```

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party but mapping a function along your list is a robust strategy for replacing loops ie,

```
ls={2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, 3, 7, 5, 4};    
f[n_]:=If[n-5<0,0,n];
f/@ls
```

It's not as terse as the pure functions but has some clarity for beginners, especially if they don't know a built-in function exists.